# Progress bar start when div is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jQuery progress bar I'm using; but I'm using it within a div that is hidden by default on page load and then is shown after a form is completed. Problem is; the progress bar is only seen progressing dependent on how fast the user completes the form. Because the progress bar is beginning on page load with the `$(document).ready(function() {`

How do I set it and call my progress bar to load after the div is shown that its in? EG. Form is complete > Next div shows THEN my progress bar starts. Below is the code I'm using for the bar.

```
var progress = setInterval(function() {
    var $bar = $('.bar');

    if ($bar.width()==400) {
        clearInterval(progress);
        $('.progress').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $bar.width($bar.width()+40);
    }
    $bar.text($bar.width()/4 + "%");
}, 900);
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Why can't you start the progress bar when the div is shown instead of inside the $(document).ready function?

Comment: By 'form is completed' do you mean when the user submits the form?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking @ChrisP what would be the best way to write that; I should use an if statement and say something like 'if this div is displayed load this script'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DL3Hn/).

Basically you need to bind the [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event on the form. In the event handler function show the progress bar and do what ever you want.

```
function showProgressBar(){
    var progress = setInterval(function() {
        $('#form').hide();
        var $bar = $('.bar');
        $bar.show();  // show it here

        if ($bar.width()==400) {
            clearInterval(progress);
            $('.progress').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $bar.width($bar.width()+40);
        }
        $bar.text($bar.width()/4 + "%");
    }, 900);

    return false;
}

$(window).load(function(){
    $('#form').submit(showProgressBar); // bind the submit event
}
```